# Parent & Child field syncing

Tags: jira

I want to write custom code to support the behavior below:
Parent A has a field called "ABC" Each Child task of Parent A has this field "ABC" as Read-only "ABC" edited in the Parent should filter down to each child every time its updated. Obviously this wouldn't be a true live sync but should call the same value as soon as the end user refreshes the page to see the updated value.

I really, want a Scripted Function that reads custom fields on a parent-task for change, and if changed carries that value over to the child-task. I am using "Script Runner" but I cannot figure out how to do this. Could you please provide the script that can be used in script runner and also i want to automate the job for all the issue's & sub-task in our instances.

I know this can be done through custom script listener but i need a script that can accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a Scripted Field. The [documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/scripted-fields.html) is quite good.

Basically you first have to get your parent issue. The issue object has a method [getParentObject()](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/server/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html#getParentObject--) that does this:

> Issue getParentObject()
>
> If this issue is a subtask, return its parent.
>
> Returns:
>
> The parent Issue, or null if the issue is not a subtask.

And then you can get the value of your parent issue's custom field. Assuming this is a simple Text field, it would look something like this:

```
String customFieldName = "My fancy custom field"

CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
Collection<CustomField> customFields = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectsByName(customFieldName)

parentIssue.getCustomFieldValue(customFields.first()) as String
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, I am quite new to this so slightly confuse as to what should i do. i have created a custom field with Scripted Field type and went to Script Field but couldn't able to find the next action. Could you get me the script which should be run.

Comment: What do you mean with "couldn't find the next action?". Go to "Manage add-ons" --> Script Fields. Your custom field will be listed there. Just click edit and either add the path to your script or enter your script inline. The script runner documentation also explains this very clearly, incl. screenshots.